# use javascript variable in html code

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use `k` and `tab_match[k]` in my list?

```
for(var k in tab_match) {
    var ligne = $("<tr><td id='show-fam-"k"><img src='stats_matching/"k".gif' alt="k" title="k" width="tab_match[k]"> </td></tr>");
    $('#img').append(ligne);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking as it's currently written. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: I *think* you just need to use string concatenation, but as Kmeixner says - It's not all that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate the string together with the values of the variables. Also note that you don't need to create the HTML in a new jQuery object - you can provide a string directly to the `append()` method. Try this:

```
for (var k in tab_match){
    $('#img').append('<tr><td id="show-fam-' + k + '"><img src="stats_matching/' + k + '.gif" alt="' + k + '" title="' + k + '" width="' + tab_match[k] + '"></td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: I forgotten this method , thank you it's very simple

Comment: don't forget `if (tab_match.hasOwnProperty(k)) {...}`

Comment: @TomDDD that's redundant if you're looping over the properties of `tab_match`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan tab_match is an object like any other. We don't know about how it was created. If in the future the code is extended and tab_match is an instance of something(or if it already is) then now this code is broken. You lose nothing by stuffing all `for in` loops with object.hasOwnProperty.

Comment: But if you're *looping over the properties* of that object, then they are guaranteed to exist. You see my point? It doesn't matter if some are missing - only those that exist at that point in time will be iterated over.